# Why does the += operator with lists alters the output of my function inside a class in python?

Tags: python, class, scope, operators

Hello I was trying to debug an issue with some classes and I came to this minimal example:

```py
class parentclass:
    a = ["a", "a"]
    b = ["b", "b"]

    def test(self, condition):
        c = self.a
        if condition:
            c += self.b
            # c = c + self.b
        print(c)


class childclass(parentclass):
    a = ["a_child", "a_child"]
    b = ["b_child", "b_child"]


child1 = childclass()

child1.test(condition=False)
child1.test(condition=True)
child1.test(condition=False)
```

Which yields to:

```
['a_child', 'a_child']
['a_child', 'a_child', 'b_child', 'b_child']
['a_child', 'a_child', 'b_child', 'b_child']
```

If I change the commented line:

```py
class parentclass:
    a = ["a", "a"]
    b = ["b", "b"]

    def test(self, condition):
        c = self.a
        if condition:
            # c += self.b
            c = c + self.b
        print(c)


class childclass(parentclass):
    a = ["a_child", "a_child"]
    b = ["b_child", "b_child"]


child1 = childclass()

child1.test(condition=False)
child1.test(condition=True)
child1.test(condition=False)
```

It works as expected:

```
['a_child', 'a_child']
['a_child', 'a_child', 'b_child', 'b_child']
['a_child', 'a_child']
```

I though the operator `+=` would make the same as in other languages like perl `.=`, where it adds the new variable to the original value.

But in this scenario it seems that this operation affects something outside the call of the function.

I was using `python 3.10` when I tested this.

Comment: `c = self.a` assign reference to list `a` to local variable `c`, `c += self.b` append list `b` to list `a` which referenced through variable `c`.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `mylist += ...` mutates the list `mylist`. It is unfortunately not equivalent to `mylist = mylist + ...`.

Comment: `+=` does add the new variable to the original value, but the original value is actually `self.a` not `c`. In your example `c` only points to `self.a` rather than having an independent `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, there is a difference between these two operations, not only in lists, but for arrays, tensors and as far as I’m aware of also primitive types. For example:

```
a += 1
```

Will be translated into - go to where a is stored, and increment its value by 1

Whereas

```
a = a+1
```

a gets reassigned with the the value of a + 1, and is stored in a different address